# ArcGIS Pro Unable to Pairwise Intersect Point with Polygon?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, intersect

I am trying to create a point from XY coordinates then use Pairwise Intersect to determine the corresponding parcel. The intersect is not returning any values. Any thoughts on the error in this code?

parcel_tax_data is a simple polygon shapefile with GCS WGS 1984 coordinate system. It appears to successfully create the PointGeometry using the XY coordinates, convert to feature class and creates the intersect output file, but there is no contents. It does not recognize the point is intersected with any of of the parcels.

```
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(parcel_tax_data).spatialReference

point = arcpy.Point(lng_lat[0], lng_lat[1])
geo_point = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, spatial_ref)

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\path\to\project", "point_feature_class", "POINT", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", spatial_ref)

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("point_feature_class", ['SHAPE@XY'])
print("Cursor Created")
cursor.insertRow(geo_point)

inFeatures = ["point_feature_class", parcel_tax_data]
intersectOutput = "point"
print(inFeatures)

arcpy.PairwiseIntersect_analysis(inFeatures, intersectOutput, "ALL")
```

Comment: I think the problem is that geo_point is a PointGeometry but your insert cursor is expecting a tuple because you specified shape@xy. Look at the help file for insert cursor, you can see shape@.